# zxing continuous scanning - iphone

Tags: iphone, reset, zxing

I've integrated the zxing library into my app but part of my requirement is to be able to continually scan QR codes.
I've accomplished this to a certain degree by dismissing and re-presenting the zxing widget but it appears to be too slow for my client.
Is there another way to reset the widget to start scanning again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to tamper with the ZXing library, fortunately it's not hard.

Add the following method to the ZXingWidgetController

In ZXingWidgetController.h

```
- (void)reset;
```

In ZXingWidgetController.m

```
- (void)reset
{
    decoding = YES;
    [overlayView setPoints:nil];
    wasCancelled = NO;
}
```

Now, in your ZXing delegate, edit the following method

```
- (void)zxingController:(ZXingWidgetController*)controller didScanResult:(NSString *)result
{
    //Handle your result as you want to

    [controller reset];
}
```

Make sure you don't call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` as it will remove the scanning view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try for another great library ZBar - http://zbar.sourceforge.net/
Its quite easy and always work for me! You must have a look into if you are scanning QR codes in your app.

Comment: ZBar doesn't support the newer iPod Touch with camera, nor the iPhone 3g, no matter how sharp the image is. (Or didn't when I last tried it.) That's why I switched to zxing. zbar also has a more restrictive license, which might be an issue.

Comment: @geon, the licence on ZBar is LGPL 2.1 which is ok for app store use (according to their FAQ) *but* users have the right to request the object files for your app so they can recompile it. Not good!